# Mongodb 3.6 using multiple conditions on aggregation lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I have two collections in my MongoDb

1. metricCollectionForms
2. metric

A `metricCollectionForms` document looks something like this

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5ea25f38afd94f0008d4e6f2"),
    "approverId": "f08ba2aa-4597-41f0-9e6c-cebf1715ba30",
    "formName": "Test Form",
    "formId": "d56209a1-4df0-48de-b6cf-d1ee50200936",
}
```

I have skipped few attributes from the document above because they are not relevant to this question.

As for the `metric` a typical document looks like this

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5ea27955bae4900008d996ba"),
    "name": "Test Metric",
    "type": "INTERNAL",
    "formula": [
        {
          "type": "FORM_FIELD",
          "formId": "d56209a1-4df0-48de-b6cf-d1ee50200936",
          "formFieldId": "dca2bacf-2cbd-480d-8289-6f3050b635fb"
        },
      {...}, {...}
    ],
    "formulaLabel": "monthly_production",
    "createdBy": "f08ba2aa-4597-41f0-9e6c-cebf1715ba30",
    "isApproved": true,
    "isActive": false
}
```

You will notice that the `formId` value from `metricCollectionForms` is being referenced  in the formula array `formId` field of the `metric` document.

So one metric can use many forms within its formula array of object.

I am trying to get list of forms and within that list return the array of metric **name** where

metric.formula.formId = formId (of the form) AND
metric.isActive = true AND
metric.isApproved = true

So far my aggregate query looks something like this:

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "metric",
        localField: "formId",
        foreignField: "formula.formId",
        as: "metrics"
    }
},
{
    $addFields: {
        metrics: "$metrics.name"
    }
}
```

Now it does return me an array of all metric names but I do not know how I can apply the isApproved and isActive true conditions on the $lookup.

I tried doing $pipeline / $match etc but nothing seems to work. Also the solution should be compatible to Mongo 3.6 as I am using this within AWS DocumentDb (which only supports 3.6).

Answer (score 1):

The pipeline form of lookup that would allow this is not available until MongoDB 4.2.

The best option in 3.6 is to follow the lookup with an `$addFields` stage with a [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#filter-aggregation) expression to remove the unwanted elements from the array.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for your example.

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "metric",
        localField: "formId",
        foreignField: "formula.formId",
        as: "metrics"
    }
},
{
    $match: {
       $and: {[
               "metrics.isApproved": true,
               "metrics.isActive": true
              ]}
    }
}
```

{ $match: {"metrics.isApproved": 'MA'}},